# API array problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

Here's the API reponse:

```json
{
  "meals": [
    {
      "strTags":"Fish,Breakfast,DateNight",
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to see following result:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<div>
  {recipe.strTags ? <Chip label={recipe.strTags.split(",")} /> : null}
</div>
```

For now it looks like this:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Pls update question and code more clearly

Comment: The way you are splitting is correct. I whould like to know how `label` in `Chip` component will be managed (because the result looks like a label's `join`)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div>
  {recipe.strTags && recipe.strTags.split(",").map((tag) => <Chip label={tag} />)}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to split your string to create array, then iterate over it using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create every single label. Remember about adding `key` property to avoid re-render issues.

Solution:

```js
<div>
  {
     recipe.strTags
        ? recipe.strTags
                .split(',')
                .map(label => (
                   <Chip label={label} key={label} />
                ))
        : null
  }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that a `Chip` component is one of these rounded boxes you want to see, you will have to create a separate `Chip` for each tag. Ie `split` the string first and the use `map` to create a `Chip` for each item in the array.

```
<div>
  {recipie.strTags 
    ? recipie.strTags.split(',').map(tag => (<Chip label={tag}/>)) 
    : null}
<div>
```